# "As .. as I am" in the beginning of sentence

Tags: grammar, phrases, poetry

Is this sentence gramatically correct? How does it sound? I suppose that nobody would probably say it this way in a casual conversation, but does it sound awkward or rather poetic to native speakers?

> As perfectionist as I am, I think the trip was just perfect! And thank
>   you all for making it so!

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would say this is not quite right, although perhaps grammatically sound.

When you say "as X as I am", you are setting up for a situation in which you actually go against X. For example:

> As perfectionist as I am, I often take shortcuts when cooking.

So you're saying that despite being perfectionist, in some situations you go against that tendency.

You might also say that despite being X, you cannot do Y (even where X is normally associated with being able to do Y). For example:

> As tall as I am, I cannot reach the top shelf.

Here we see the same idea, namely that of the second clause contradicting the expectation normally associated with the first clause.

Your example is different. It is saying that you have high standards of perfection, but that this trip has lived up to them. In other words, it must be a perfect trip if *you* say it is! The implication is that despite your high standards, which lead to the expectation that you will judge the trip to be unsuccessful, you actually judge it to be successful. But even though there is a similar kind of contradiction here between the first and second clauses, it is too elliptical -- that is, it is implied too subtly. That is what makes it sound unnatural.

Comment: I disagree here: in "As X as I am..." X should be an adjective, like *tall,* or *perfect*. The intended meaning in the "perfectionist" example is "Even though I am a perfectionist," and that's a far better way of saying it; if you really want *as...as,* then it's "As much as I am a perfectionist..."

Comment: A grain of salt because English isn't my mother tongue: I believe the sentence would make sense if you omit the second 'as' if you want to use a noun in it, so an example would be: "As perfectionist I am, I often take shortcuts when cooking."